# Kendo UI sync() not firing when datasource._destroyed is populated (dirty)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Here is slimmed down version of code:

```
gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: 'Equipment'
            },
            destroy: {
                url: 'Equipment',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "DELETE"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation == "read") {
                    return "this=works-fine";
                } else {
                    alert('not reading');
                    return kendo.stringify(options.models);
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            id: "EquipmentId",
            fields: {
                Value: { type: "number" }
            }
        }
    });

kendoGrid = gridObj.kendoGrid({
        dataSource: gridDataSource,
        selectable: 'row',
        navigatable: true,
        change: rowSelect,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: false,
        columns: [
            { field: "Value" },
        ]
    }).data('kendoGrid');
```

And the read works just fine, I remove a row (or many) with this (selectedRow is populated correctly, just skipped for brevity):

```
    $('#footer-remove').off().on('click', function () {
        kendoGrid.removeRow('table tr[data-uid="' + selectedRow.uid + '"]');
        console.log(gridDataSource._destroyed);
    });
```

And its shows up in gridDataSource._destroyed, all my tests all show that the gridDataSource is dirty.

When I call sync, nothing happens if I am just deleting.  What am I missing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `editable` to `true` in the initialization of the `grid`.

```
kendoGrid = gridObj.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: gridDataSource,
    selectable: 'row',
    navigatable: true,
    change: rowSelect,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: false,
    editable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "Value" },
    ]
}).data('kendoGrid');
```

If you don't want the cell to be *updatable* (just being removed) then you should set `editable` as follow:

```
editable: {
    destroy: true,
    update: false
},
```

Also, setting `editable.confirmation` to `false` disable a popup prompting for confirmation when deleting.

**EDIT**:

The reason why `destroy` is not being executed is that there is an error in the `Datasource` definition, `schema` should contain `model` element and then the definition (you missed `model`).

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "EquipmentId",
        fields: {
            Value: { type: "number" }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/dq6jh3yp/4/

Comment: The row is removed fine from the datasource and the grid, the problem is that when I call: gridDataSource.sync(), nothing happens - the destroy method is not called.  In your example "destroy.op" is never logged

Comment: Check my **EDIT**, the problem was in the Schema definition.